# Why DOESN'T strcpy cause a segmentation fault when writing to a shorter array?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault, strcpy

I'm trying to understand c strings and pointers better. I was playing with `strcpy`, and I expected the code below to cause a segmentation fault, but to my surprise, it did not.

```
char a [] = "hello there";
char b [] = "yay";
strcpy(b, a);
puts(a);
puts(b);
```

Result:

```
hello there
hello there
```

When `strcpy` gets to the second "l" in "hello", shouldn't the string pointed to by `b` be out of memory slots? I would have thought that after the third byte, `strcpy` would run out of allocated memory in the `b` array, start writing to unallocated memory, or memory allocated to another pointer, and cause a segmentation fault.

I'd appreciate help understanding this better. Thanks!

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.  That's why.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, writing outside allocated memory causes undefined behavior, which means sometimes it will cause a segmentation fault, but other weird stuff can happen too, like strcpy unexpectedly "succeeding"?

Comment: You might like to read [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). Suppose you park your car and leave the parking brake off: the car might roll away, it might not. There are no promises from the Careless Parking Police. Suppose you sit in a reserved seat in a playhouse: its owner might demand it , might not show up, or may already be sitting in the seat, again no promises.

Comment: @WeatherVane I doubt that the owner will be sitting in his reserved seat if you are already sitting in it ;-)

Comment: @Jabberwocky my point is there will be trouble (: but not in all cases. The owner may already be in it.